# How can I catch bees?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know from previous *Animal Crossing* games that it's possible to catch the bees that fall out of trees (not the free roaming honeybees), assuming you manage to do so before they sting you. Sadly, I'm not having much success at capturing them in *New Leaf*. I try to turn around to capture them, but I always get stung before I can.

How can I catch the bees that fall out of trees in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a good video that shows a strategy for catching bees:

Basically, you want to run away from them as soon as you can, and wait for them to follow you (run 6-8 squares away), and the moment the bees come on screen, press A as soon as they appear and you should catch them. In the video, she suggests running up, so you don't have to really turn much to be facing the bees when they appear.

Comment: Note that bees move significantly slower compared to the first animal crossing. As long as you actually have a net and are prepared it's not really hard anymore.

Comment: She has perfect peaches, just like me. yay

Answer (score 0):

I have my own method for doing it, and it works pretty well.

Shake on one side of the tree, and when the hive drops out and lands on one lower-corner position, run to the corresponding upper corner position (or slightly closer - don't get too close, they'll reach you before you can swing). Then open your pockets and equip the net. If you're positioned reasonably, you can swing the net immediately on closing your pockets, and catch the bee.

The upside to this is that there's little by way of timing involved, you just need to press B to close the pockets and then mash A to swing as soon as possible. The downside is that if you misjudge position, you're probably going to get stung.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard. I have wild world and city folk and on both me and my brother haven't caught one yet. What you do is you shake a tree until a hive falls out. Then, you run north and get your net out. Right when they come, you turn around and catch them.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Press the left button on the d-pad. It will switch to your net and make you face the bees. Let them get a little closer, and SWING! Then sell the bees for 2,000 bells. And sell the hive for an additional 500 bells. But if you failed, take the beehive anyway and sell it, then talk to your villagers. Some may laugh at you, some may take pity on you, some may say to take medicine, and some may give you medicine! That medicine will heal your beestings.